# Popup window to always appear fixed to top edge BUT scrolls with entire page if content larger than screen height?

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, scroll, popup

Let me try and make sense. I have a search page that returns lots of search results just like Google. Each of those search results have a trigger (via an icon using onmouseover) to access more info in a popup window that pops up to the right of all the search results, just like google. Here is what I want from the popup window:

- No matter if I am looking at the first search result at the top of the page, or the last search result way down at the bottom of the page, I want the popup window to align itself with the top edge of the screen, regardless of where I am vertically on the page (similar to fixed)
- BUT, if the popup window happens to contain more data then the vertical screen height allows, instead of the popup window creating scrollbars internally, I want the popup window to scroll right along with everything else on the page (similar to absolute)
- The problem is that fixed chops off data that goes below the bottom of the visible browser window height making it inaccesible without internal scrollbars. With absolute, the popup scrolls along with all the other stuff on the page which is great and what I want, but it always appears at the very top of the page, even when I am at the bottom of the page, making it invisible to the user if the results list is very long.

Its like I am trying to combine the two methods in a way. So to summarize:

- When I trigger a popup via onmouseover, the popup window should affix itself to top edge always no matter where I am vertically, but if its content is vertically taller than the screen allows, I should be able to scroll the entire page down to see the rest of it. I should not have to use internal scrollbars within the popup window like fixed.

Is this possible and how should I go about it? Thanks!

Comment: By the way, just to try and make it more clear, I could try and say it like this. When a user triggers my onmouseover, it should popup the window using fixed, so that it shows up along the top edge no matter where you are vertically. But, as soon the window has popped up fixed, somehow, the fixed needs to be changed to absolute without the popup moving anywhere. That way, and at that point, the user can scroll the entire page down to see anything missing if contents are too tall to fit vertically in the popup without using fixed style internal scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need JavaScript.

First, make set the popup `div`s to `position: absolute`. This will act like `fixed` in that it can go anywhere on the page easily through `left` and `top`, but it still scrolls with the page.

On link hover, make the JS detect the browser's scroll position (through `window.offsetY` or `$(window).scrollTop()` in jQuery). Apply this offset to the popup:

```
$('.link').on('click', function () {
    $('.preview').css('top', $(window).scrollTop());
});
```

Remember also to tweak the other CSS properties of the popup to suit your needs - however, most of that can be done in CSS; the only JS you really need is for the `top` property.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GWvNx/